# Lithuanian minhag for talis katan material

Tags: minhag, history, clothing, ashkenazi, tallit-katan

Not an halachic question, but we can read many things about talis katan: wool over cotton, tzitzis out or in, etc. It seems that the Lithuanian minhag was to tuck them in, but what about the material? Was it cotton as a majority? What about Slobodka, Mir, Vilna, etc.: any differences?

Comment: If you are referring to the yeshivos of Slabodka and Mir, I would be surprised if they had specific personal minhagim, as students congregated there from many towns.

Comment: You're right ! So let's focus on Lithuanian minhag.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might find your answer in the book [Minhagei Lita](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2009/10/review-minhagei-lita.html) for information dealing with Litvishe Minhagim. It was authored by Rabbi Menachem Mendel Poliakoff ZY"A, the father of a Rebi and Chavrusa of mine.

Comment: I've checked in sefer Minhagei Lita and there is no mention of beged material. Could you ask to a suitable acquaintance ? Thanks

Comment: IIRC, the sefer *Minhagei Lita* does mention that the Lithuanian custom was to tuck them in.

Comment: The Gr"a held by cotton, or so I have heard, although the Rama (Polin, then Polin-Lita) followed the B"Y on wool. Rav Soloveitchik ztz"l followed the Gr"a, I assume, as I am unsure of the details, because this was the minhag of the Brisker Rov.

Answer (score -1):

The modern-day Halachic preference in certain circles for cotton as a material for tallis katan stems primarily from rulings of the Chazon Ish, one of which is that on hot summer days, when it is uncomfortable to wear wool, one does not fulfill the mitzvah of tzitzis with wool. 
There is a detailed discussion about it [here](https://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?cat_id=4&topic_id=1626421&forum_id=771).

The above-mentioned reason is not so relevant to Northern Europe. We may safely assume that the European yeshivos followed the established Halachic practice of the pre-Chazon Ish era, which shows a preference for wool. (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 9:1, Mishnah Berurah ad loc)

Comment: This isn't right. The established pre chazon ish Ashkenazi tradition was not to have a preference for wool, and treat all materials as biblically obligated. See the Rama.

Comment: Please see the Mishnah Berurah, who shows a preference for wool.

Comment: I've seen it. It is not the established Ashkenazi tradition. The Mishna Berura is an important and interesting work, but it isn't safe to assume that everyone followed his rulings before it